# How to get my MG6200 printer to work on wireless with 18.04

Tags: 18.04

Since upgrading from UBUNTU 16 to 18 my MG6200 no long works via Wireless
It works using Windows & Ubuntu 14 so I think it might be the driver.
Cannon MG6200 series-CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.10-pre2 in Ubuntu 14 works but
 Cannon MG6200 series-CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13 does not,I get a message that says printer not accepting job.